# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of undefined slideshow up

Tags: javascript, typeerror

Works in Firefox but not in other browsers.

```
function slideshowUp() {
    num = num + 1
    if (num == 4) {
        num = 1
    }
    document.mypic.src = eval("img" + num + ".src")
    document.jenn.lopez.value = eval("text" + num)
}
```

The error we get from Chrome:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of undefined ps.html:39
>   slideshowUp ps.html:39 (anonymous function)

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        var num=1
        img1 = new Image ()
        img1.src = "images/Lopez_Project_web.jpg"
        img2 = new Image ()
        img2.src = "images/Lopez_magazine_web.jpg"
        img3 = new Image ()
        img3.src = "images/collage_web.jpg"

        text1 = "Mask of Flight"
        text2 = "Training 101"
        text3 = "Collage"

        function slideshowUp()
        {
        num=num+1
        if (num==4)
        {num=1}
        document.mypic.src=eval("img"+num+".src")
        document.jenn.lopez.value=eval("text"+num)
        }

        function slideshowBack()
        {
        num=num-1
        if (num==0)
        {num=3}
        document.mypic.src=eval("img"+num+".src")
        document.jenn.lopez.value=eval("text"+num)
        }

    </script>
</header><br>
 <div class="c1">
    <a href="JavaScript:slideshowBack()"><img src="images/back.png" alt="Back" align="left"></a>
    <a href="JavaScript:slideshowUp()"><img src="images/next.png" alt="Next" align="right"></a>

    <img src="images/Lopez_Project_web.jpg" alt= "Mask of Flight"  id="mypic">
    <p>

    <form name="jenn">
    <input type="text" name="lopez" value="Mask of Flight">
    </form>
```

This is my code it works in Firefox, but not IE or Chrome

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML markup which `document.mypic` references as well as `document.jenn.lopez`

Comment: Wow that is heinous with the evals.  Has there been a variable `mypic` set on document?

Comment: Instead of `eval`, use `window["img"+num+".src"]` and `window["text"+num]`. It works just as well (assuming the variables are global, which I assume they are). Eval is generally best avoided unless there is **really** no other way.

Comment: I tried changing the eval to windows and it stopped working in both Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: try change all the `document.mypic` etc to `window.mypic`. `document.mypic` shouldn't even be working in firefox. the browser creates objects for all elements with ID, but it is in the window scope. I wonder why they're accessible in `document` for firefox

Comment: kennypu is this by itself or am I changing the evals also?